# Не работает пример из видеоурока

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.gest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

    private TextView txt;
    private GestureDetectorCompat gd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id. textHello);
        gd = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
        gd.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
        gd.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        txt.setText("onLongPress: " + motionEvent.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

> error: cannot find symbol variable motionEvent

Если переименовать `motionEvent` в `MotionEvent`, то будет другая ошибка:

> error: non-static method toString() cannot be referenced from a static
>   context

Comment: Ссылку на урок то добавьте.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptLCqfSBk9A&list=PL0lO_mIqDDFW13-lP3IgK9lZoM1M-oPl4&index=13&t=0s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в методе `onLongPress` переменная называется `e`, а в консоль вы пытаетесь вывести какой-то `motionEvent`. Замените `motionEvent.toString()` на `e.toString()`.

```
@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    txt.setText("onLongPress: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! работает)